# Render a PDF from Static Resources in a VF page

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rerender

I have a Static Resource that is a PDF.

How can I show it on a VF page? I also, want it to be 100% of the VF page.

Here is the code I tried that doesn't display the image:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:imagevalue="https://na34.salesforce.com/resource/1449015293000/PDFFile"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be a VF page? Most browsers will open a pdf just like you describe (full screen). If you send a user to the static resource's URL then it should display fine.

You can do it like this

```
<a target="_blank" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.THENAME)}">Click Here for
PDF<\a>
```